# Server side support for Google TV

Tags: google-tv

Does Google Server provide any server side support for Google TV devices? Does it provides any plugin or installables specific to Google? For example, Google advertisement or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing specific that's targeted at the developer.   We support our apps with significant server side infrastructure.  (Beyond that statement I'm not going to discuss specifics)

Google App Engine is targeted at all developers and is an excellent way to provide server side support for your apps.